# Parsing string using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, typetoken

I have a repsonse, which has array but in string, i need to parse that using GSON.

Firstly, I need to create a json array for that like this :

```
val data = JSONArray(response)
```

then I use GSON for parsing.

My reponse is as follow :

```
[{"Response":"true","ServerMsg":"[{\"Type\":\"Settled\",\"Items\":\"[{\\\"ID\\\":\\\" 1\\\",\\\"Date\\\":\\\" 14 May 18\\\",\\\"Amount\\\":\\\" 1458 USD\\\",\\\"ReferenceID\\\":\\\" ECR18-25-0002\\\"}]\",\"Amount\":1458},{\"Type\":\"Open\",\"Items\":\"[]\",\"Amount\":0}]","ErrorID":"OK","ErrorMsg":null}]
```

I tried using TypeToken

```
val gson = Gson()
  val listTyle = object : TypeToken<List<Loandata>>() {}.type
  loanList = gson.fromJson<List<Loandata>>(response, listTyle) as ArrayList<Loandata>?
```

but this did not work, can any one suggest how can i parse the string directly in my POJO class using gson without creating a jsonarray.

Answer (score 0):

It should not contain // characters. Before passing to GSON remove all // from your json response and then pass to GSON function.
Your JSON should be look like this.

```
[{
    "Response": "true",
    "ServerMsg": [{
        "Type": "Settled",
        "Items ": [{
            "ID": " 1",
            "Date": " 14 May 18",
            "Amount": " 1458 USD",
            "ReferenceID": " ECR18-25-0002"
        }],
        "Amount ": 1458
    }, {
        "Type ": "Open ",
        "Items ": " []",
        "Amount ": 0
    }],
    "ErrorID": "OK",
    "ErrorMsg": null
}]
```